# Doctrine 2 many-to-one relationship not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables in my database: `user` and `media_contact`. The `media_contact` table has a `user_id`, so, obviously, my intent is to be able to select media contacts based on a user.

The problem I'm having is that this fails:

```
// VNN/PressboxBundle/Entity/User.php
// $this in this case is a User object with id 26
$customContacts = $em->getRepository('VNNPressboxBundle:MediaContact')->findByUser($this);
```

This gives me nothing. `$customContacts` is empty. But:

```
mysql> select * from media_contact where user_id=26;
+-----+-------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+
| id  | name        | email                 | media_area_id | user_id |
+-----+-------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+
| 177 | Jason Swett | jason.swett@gmail.com |          NULL |      26 |
| 183 | Sam         | sam@sam.com           |          NULL |      26 |
+-----+-------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It should really be returning two objects. I really don't understand why this is happening.

Here are my annotations:

```
// User.php

/** 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MediaContact", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $mediaContacts;
```

-

```
// MediaContact.php
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="mediaContacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$this->getId()` instead of `$this` in order for it to work:

```
$customContacts = $em->getRepository('VNNPressboxBundle:MediaContact')->findByUser($this->getId());
```

Comment: If I have to do all that stuff, what are the `findBy()` methods for? Those methods worked in Symfony < 2.0. Did they just include silently-failing versions of the `findBy()` methods in Symfony2 (or Doctrine 2 or whatever) as a joke?

Comment: Also, I'm not joining anything. The analogous raw SQL query would be `SELECT * FROM media_contact WHERE user_id = 26`. If I have to do a join in Doctrine just to execute that query, that would be pathetic. I doubt that that's the case.

Comment: findBy methods are useful for querying the Entity you are working on. In your case: VNNPressboxBundle:MediaContact . In order to query the related user Entity you need to build the query using JOIN, by using DQL *OR* a custom method in your Repository class.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page. Maybe it's me, sorry. I'm using methods like `$repo->findOneByName($someName)`, `$repo->findByFooId($someId)` in other places in my applications and those are working fine. No need to bring joins into the picture. The number of tables I'm querying on is 1. `SELECT * FROM media_contact WHERE user_id = 26`. If I have to do a JOIN, use DQL, or create a custom method just to run THAT query, then that seems to me like an astonishingly bad design, and I don't believe that that's the way it is.

Comment: That works. Thanks! So apparently `findByUser()` is expecting an *id*, not a *User*. It seems to me that a method called `findByUser()` should take a `User` and a method called `findByUserId()` should take an id. And I believe that's how it used to work. But evidently, for some stupid reason, they changed it.